# 8-bit binary to bcd converter Verilog

Tags: computer-architecture, logic, binary

We have been given task to write a 8-bit binary to bcd converter Verilog code, using structural code NOT behavioural, is it possible to guide us how can we create 8-bit binary to bcd converter using two 4-bit converter instances ?

Comment: You should post that on electronics.stackexchange.com. Most definitely.

Comment: `create 8-bit binary to bcd converter using two 4-bit converter instances` You may want to re-think this approach. Or research what were common methods for the conversion mentioned. (*Nobody* did 4-bit binary to 4 bit BCD+carry converters for semi-obvious reasons.)

Comment: Belatedly, it occurred to me that `NOT behavioural` does *not* spell [combinational logic (circuit)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinational_logic). Not that I can even imagine a useful *cascadable 4-bit binary to BCD converter*.